# Is it possible to change the speed of an animation for a single rig separately from other rigs in the scene?

Tags: animation, objects

I am fairly new to blender and animation in general so forgive me if I am missing something. I have a scene in which I would like to slow down the animation of a single rig without affecting other animations in the scene. Is there any simple solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the timeline, for simple animations, or the Dope Sheet or Curve editor for more complex animations to *scale* the animation of a particular rig.

Slowing down an animation is the same as moving each keyframe a certain distance down the time line.  To do this, in pose mode, select all of the bones that have keyframes you want to move.  Make sure that the current frame is set to 1 and then scale by typing **sx** where number is the scale factor.

If you want to slow the animation down, scale by a number larger than 1.  Scaling by 2 will move each keyframe twice as far from the origin as it was, and thus it will take twice as long to perform that animation, for example.